# Google cloud storage get object size api

Tags: google-api, google-cloud-storage

Is there a way to get the size in bytes of a folder from google cloud storage through an API?
I saw there is a du command for the https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/du for gsutil. But I didn't find anywhere if it is possible to get this data through an API.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found that this can be done by calling the list method from this api https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/objects. The objects have a size property and you can put a prefix if you want the get only the objects from a specific path.

Comment: Cloud Storage doesn't have the concept of "folders", although some tools (like gsutil) attempt to create that illusion via listing objects, supplying prefixes and using "/" as a delimiter.  If you have two objects, "dir1/a" and "dir1/b", they're just sharing a common name prefix, "dir1/".  To get the size of all objects with a given prefix, you need to list them, fetching the "size" attribute of each and summing those values.